# In Apache Druid, Is it possible to get the value a previous row?

Tags: druid

In Apache Druid, when writing a query, is it possible to get the value a previous row? For e.g., in MySQL I can do that by setting a variable value. I want todo this to find the difference between the previous end time and the current start time of an event